# putting a text code instead of a symbol in XML

Tags: xml, text

Is there a way to put text code instead of the symbol??
For examlple, a text code of "『" is 300E. I want to put the text code"300E" with the other symbols in XML below.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<charlist>
    <list>
        <title name="symbol">1</title>`
     `<chr><![CDATA[㎣㎎㎏㎍ℓ㎖㎗㎘㏊㎾㏄㎸㏏㎈㎉￦￡￥＋－‥㉿Ω]]></chr>
    </list>`

Comment: and, someome can teach me how to array by the key "enter" on my keyboard the source in my writing??

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to make a newline using escape sequences? `\n` is `&#xa;` and `\r` is `&#xd;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#x300E;` but needs to be outside of CDATA sections.